# MomentJs isBetween() function is not returning expected result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using `momentjs` for fetching current time. Then I need to check is it between the specified range or not. Let me show what I have done. I am using `isBetween` function that is returning unexpected output.

```
var now = moment().tz("America/Edmonton").format('LT');
var format = 'hh:mm:ss';
var time = moment(now,format),
beforeTime = moment(isha_adhan, format);
afterTime = moment(fajr_adhan, format);
console.log("time: ");
console.log(time);
console.log("beforeTime: ");
console.log(beforeTime);
console.log("afterTime:");
console.log(afterTime);

if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
    console.log('is between Isha and Fajr');
} else {
    console.log('is not between Isha and Fajr');
}
```

This always execute the else statement. Here is the console output.

```
time: 
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "5:06 AM", _f: "hh:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
beforeTime: 
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "6:05 PM", _f: "hh:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
afterTime:
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "6:33 AM", _f: "hh:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
is not between Isha and Fajr
```

Console output in image Please see here [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0BSW.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

MomentJs will consider `beforeTime` and `afterTime` to be in the same day (since you are not passing any dates here).

If you are comparing between two different dates, you should include them in your Moment object.

Here is a working example of your code (The current time is 3:30 PM):

```
var now = '2019-01-01 ' + moment().format('LT');
var format = 'Y-m-d h:mm A';
var time = moment(now,format),
beforeTime = moment('2019-01-01 3:05 PM', format);
afterTime = moment('2019-01-02 6:33 AM', format);
console.log("time: ");
console.log(time);
console.log("beforeTime: ");
console.log(beforeTime);
console.log("afterTime:");
console.log(afterTime);

if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
    console.log('is between Isha and Fajr');
} else {
    console.log('is not between Isha and Fajr');
}
```