# isBetween method of moment.js is showing error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js in one of my projects. In it, I have the following code to check if the current time is between say openTime & closeTime.

```
    function open_sesame(){
    var format = 'HH:mm:ss A';

    var time         = moment().format('HH:mm:ss A');
    var winOpenTime  = moment('10:00:00 AM', format);
    var winCloseTime = moment('10:15:00 AM', format);

    console.log(time);
    console.log(winOpenTime);
    console.log(winCloseTime);
    if (time.isBetween(winOpenTime, winCloseTime, null, '[]')) {
      console.log('is between');
    } else {
        console.log('is not between');
      //jQuery('#random_no_container').html('is not between');
    }
}

window.setInterval(function(){
   open_sesame();
}, 1000);  // Change Interval here to test. For eg: 5000 for 5 sec
```

> It's giving me the error time.isBetween is not a function

My console screenshot is[image]

Please tell me what's wrong with my code with some example. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071410/6299168
It's already here

Comment: here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s90fapyc/2/ - of your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Always Helping. Your code is working perfectly for me.